# r cumulative plot simplication and what should it be called

Tags: r, statistics

I have a numeric vector `data`. I need to gather the following data,  i.e., histogram, but in a cumulative sense.

```
a=c()
s=seq(0,1000,10)
for(i in s)
{
    a<-c(a,length(data[data>=i]))
}
plot(s,a)
```

How can I make this vectorized, and what should this operation be called? It is currently not very good, because I have to know the range in order to write `s` in the above, is there any existing function in `R` that does this operation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this??

```
set.seed(1)          # for reproducible example
data <- rnorm(100)   # random sample from N(0,1)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))    # set up graphics device for 2 plots

z <- hist(data,ylab="Counts",main="Histogram")
barplot(cumsum(z$counts), names.arg=z$breaks[-1],main="Cuml. Histogram")
```

[image]

This takes advantage of the fact that the `hist(...)` function not only plots a histogram, but returns and object of type `histogram`. This object has elements `$breaks` containing upper and lower limits on the histogram bins, and `$counts` containing the count of data in each bin. The `cumsum` function calculates the cumulative sum. So the plot on the right is just the cumulative sum of the counts vs. the breaks.

Another, slightly simpler way to do this is to "hack" the histogram object returned by `hist(...)` and then use `plot(...)` on that:

```
z <- hist(data,ylab="Counts",main="Histogram")
z$counts <- cumsum(z$counts)
plot(z, main="Cuml. Histogram")
```

[image]

Finally, `ecdf(...)` (empirical cumulative distribution function) returns a *function* that can be plotted easily.

```
plot(ecdf(data))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would convert to factors with as many levels as you want bins, and then use `table` and `cumsum` on that.

For example:

```
# Create some fake data:
> tst = sample(1:50,10)
> tst
 [1] 33  7 13 19  1 18 39 15 21 25

# create a vector of factors with all possible levels from "min(tst)" until "max(tst)":
> tst2 = factor(as.character(tst),levels=paste0(min(tst):max(tst)))
> tst2
 [1] 33 7  13 19 1  18 39 15 21 25
39 Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 ... 39

# finally, get in one (vectorized) operation the distribution of values >= levels (for each level):
> cumsum(table(tst2))
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 
 1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  4  4  4  5  6  6  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8 
29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
 8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9  9  9 10
```

Does this help?

## edit:

I just realized that this gives you the number of items whose value is less than a given threshold. You can obtain what you want with:

```
> tst3 = rev(cumsum(table(tst2)))
> names(tst3) = rev(names(tst3))
> tst3
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 
10  9  9  9  9  9  9  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  7  7  7  7  6  6  5  4  4  4  3  3  2 
29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 
 2  2  2  2  2  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

## edit 2:

Much simpler in fact:

```
> sapply(min(tst):max(tst), function(x)sum(tst>=x))
 [1] 10  9  9  9  9  9  9  8  8  8  8  8  8  7  7  6  6  6  5  4  4  3  3  3  3  2
[27]  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  1  1  1  1  1
```